# DateField issues in Django

Tags: python, django, datetime

I am struggling with some DateTime issues in Django. I believe it all comes down to data types and conversions and I am just not quite getting it. I would greatly appreciate if someone could clean up my code, as posted below. I would ask also not to change too much. I am very new to programming. I'm certain that there are better ways to accomplish what I am trying to do, but my understanding is limited to doing things a certain way. So if you could help me make this work without wholesale changes I would really appreciate it.

Okay...

As a learning project I am building a very basic "Travel App" in Django (Python 2, Django 1). I want users to be able to enter a start and end date for a trip. The start date must be in the future and the end date must be after the start date.

First, I create my Trip table in models:

```
class Trip(models.Model):
    destination = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    description = models.TextField()
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True)

    travelers = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="trips")

    planned_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="trips_added")

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = TripManager()
```

I think all is well with this.

Also in models, I set up both a validation and an add method for the "add trip" form. Here is what I have as of now - I know there are some errors in here:

```
class TripManager(models.Manager):

    def trip_validation(self, postData):

        start_date = datetime.strptime(postData['start_date'], "%Y-%m-%d")
        end_date = datetime.strptime(postData['end_date'], "%Y-%m-%d")

        errors = {}

        if len(postData['destination']) < 1:
            errors['destination'] = 'You must enter trip destination.'

        if len(postData['description']) < 1:
            errors['description'] = 'You must enter trip description.'

        if len(postData['start_date']) < 1:
            errors['start_date'] = 'Please enter a start date for your trip.'
        elif not start_date > timezone.now():
            errors['start_date'] = 'Your trip start date must be in the future.'

        if len(postData['end_date']) < 1:
            errors['end_date'] = 'Please enter an end date for your trip.'
        elif not self.end_date > self.start_date:
            errors['end_date'] = 'Trip end date must be after start date.'

        return errors

    def trip_add(self, postData, user_id):
        destination = postData['destination']
        description = postData['description']
        start_date = datetime.strptime(postData['start_date'], "%Y-%m-%d")
        end_date = datetime.strptime(postData['end_date'], "%Y-%m-%d")
        user_obj = User.objects.get(id=user_id)

        return self.create(destination=postData['destination'], description=postData['description'], start_date=postData['start_date'], end_date=postData['end_date'], planned_by=user_obj)
```

Right now, when I run the app, I am not able to validate whether the user entered a date at all - I get `time data '' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'`. So that's the first hurdle, but I suspect that once I have a grasp on that the rest of the code will fall in line more easily.

I have not included what I do in views, which is call the trip_validation and trip_add methods, place errors into a context dict, etc, because I think that is OK (or at least Django isn't complaining about that yet because it can't get there!).

Thank you.

**Update**

I have been asked to post views and full traceback so here comes...

add_trip method in views:

```
def add_trip(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        errors = Trip.objects.trip_validation(request.POST)

        if not errors:
            trip = Trip.objects.trip_add(request.POST, request.session['uid'])
            # redirect to individual trip page
            return render(request, 'html_files/add.html')

        else:
            context = {
                'errors' : errors
            }
            return render(request, 'html_files/add.html', context=context)

    elif request.method == "GET":
        first_name = User.objects.get(id=request.session['uid']).first_name

        context = {
            'first_name' : first_name,
        }
    return render(request, 'html_files/add.html', context=context)
```

Currently, I am simply trying to submit the form with an empty "start date" field in hopes of seeing the error, via the context dict, that says 'Please enter a start date for your trip.' I have not been able to get that far into the code to work.

Traceback:

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/gbroesche/Desktop/TravelBuddy/apps/trips/views.py" in add_trip
  22.       errors = Trip.objects.trip_validation(request.POST)

File "/Users/gbroesche/Desktop/TravelBuddy/apps/trips/models.py" in trip_validation
  15.       start_date = datetime.strptime(postData['start_date'], "%Y-%m-%d")

File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py" in _strptime
  325.                          (data_string, format))

Exception Type: ValueError at /trips/add/
Exception Value: time data '' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'
```

Comment: You are not showing any form so far.

Comment: Do you mean my form in my template? I am fairly comfortable with that portion. I am not using Django built-in forms, but building the form the old fashioned way in html.

Comment: This code is a bit odd. Why do you have validation methods in a Manager? Usually that would be done in a form. Nevertheless, we can't help with the actual question because you have not posted the views code and the full traceback.

Comment: could you `print postData['start_date']` and give the output?

Comment: Really, don't do this. Use a form. What's what they're for.

Comment: Daniel, yes I definitely need to learn forms. But I am trying to make it work this way for now.

Comment: Argo, I'm not sure at what point in the code I should do that... (?)